Why are my pedal cleats rattling?
I have used SPD cleats and pedals for many years. Recently I've noticed that a particular combination of pedals and shoes are rattling when I pedal normally. Other combinations rattle less.
The pedals in question I have regreased the bearing of several times over their lifetime. I've checked that they are not wobbling on the axel. I've also checked that the cleat bolts which are secure in the shoe and the cleats themselves are fairly new.
EDIT: I also tightened up the pedal release adjuster screw several notches on each and and although it's noticeably harder to unclip, the pedal still rattles, apparently in a backwards-forwards direction when the foot is level.
However, the pedals have now done over 30000 miles. I've given them careful maintenance as mentioned, but perhaps they've simply become worn, so loose?



How much wear do the various cleats have?  Maybe the most-worn one(s) rattle more?

This is a good question and one I'll try to assess properly by comparing a few.

Try clipping in just the shoes and observe for wiggle room. Also, turning up the release tension won’t help. The pedal isn’t actively clamping onto the cleats—adjusting the tension only changes how hard it is to enter and exit the pedal.

In your second image, the cleat contact point where the tip of the cleat hooks in looks somewhat worn out. This might be already enough to make the cleat wobble slightly. As already mentioned in the comments, the cleat is not pressed into position by the force of the spring. Therefore, if the contact points between cleat and pedal are only slightly worn out, the cleat will no longer fit snug. Instead, it will have some wiggle room to slide back and forth which may come out as some rattling.
I had a similar case recently where the cleat on one shoe was ground off a bit (it just looked a little more polished than the other side). This was enough to have it slip back and forth with every pedal stroke. The cleat had about 10000 km with maybe 30% of it on gravel with rather abrasive fine dust.
So my take would be a worn out cleat, pedal, or both.

Good eye--the left pedal (second image) is noticeably worn. OP, do you have a habit of clipping out the left foot? There is visible wear towards the inside of the pedal on the front piece, which is exactly where you'd expect wear to be given that you're swinging your heel outwards.

@MaplePanda Good detective work! Yes, I do indeed unclip more often with the left foot as, living in the UK, this is the kerb side.

Thanks, this is a good answer. I should've posted photos of the cleats at well. I thought they were new, but when I swapped them for some definitely new ones, the rattling has all but disappeared. Notably, there's still a slight movement in the left pedal, so "both" is probably the correct answer.
